# How to Access Windows Partition/Drives

Tags: boot, drive

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 from bootable Pen Drive and during the installation I had overwritten it on previously run Windows 7. Now I am unable to access the Windows partition D Drive, E Drive, F Drive from Ubuntu.

How can I access files under partition drives on my PC. What I have to do? Please provide GUI instructions, if not commands will do it for me.

Comment: POst this from a terminal in Ubuntu. sudo parted -l

Comment: You can access it using ext2 read software.

Comment: You do know that Linux has no notion of more than one actual drive, right?  If not, you should learn a little about the Linux filesystem, where everything is mounted to one tree starting at the root.  Windows drives are usually mounted automatically in the directory /media, by label or UUID.

Comment: @MartyFried I am sorry i made a mistake. This software actually mount linux partitions on windows for the sake of copy purpose.

Comment: Run this command `sudo blkid` on terminal(ctrl+Alt+T) and then post it's output on your question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj : if she wants a gui, she could also launch `gnome-disks` and see the partitions with nice images and everything, but I agree that command-lines are way more useful and clear for situations like this one.